# How To Echo A Multi Dimensional Array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have string data

```
$data="100,200,300,400|500,600,700,800|900,100,200,300|400,500,600,700|800,900,100,200|300,400,500,600|700,800,900,100";
```

and i want get result like this

```
a   |b   |c   |d   |
100 |200 |300 |400 |
500 |600 |700 |800 |
900 |100 |200 |300 |
.   |.   |.   |.   |
etc |etc |etc |etc |
```

what i have to do to get result like that

i new in programming and didnt know about multidimensional array

all i know i explode this string twice

```
$data = explode(';',$data);
foreach($data as &$d)
    $d=explode(':',$d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the second argument to str_pad to change how much padding each element in the row has.

```
<?php
$data="100,200,300,400|500,600,700,800|900,100,200,300|400,500,600,700|800,900,100,200|300,400,500,600|700,800,900,100";

$rows = explode("|", $data);
$headers = "a,b,c,d";
array_unshift($rows, $headers);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $parts = explode(",", $row);
  foreach ($parts as $part) {
    echo str_pad($part, 10) . "|";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a         |b         |c         |d         |
100       |200       |300       |400       |
500       |600       |700       |800       |
900       |100       |200       |300       |
400       |500       |600       |700       |
800       |900       |100       |200       |
300       |400       |500       |600       |
700       |800       |900       |100       |
```

If you are going to have varying data, but always want to have at least 1 space between the values and the column seperator, then you can use the following:

```
<?php
$data="100,200,30,400|500,600,70,8000|900,100,200,300|4004532,500,60,700|800,900,100,200|300,400,500,600|700,800,900,100";

function splitvals($str) {
  return explode(",", $str);
}

$multi_data = array_map('splitvals', explode('|', $data));
array_unshift($multi_data, null);
$val_for_sizes = call_user_func_array('array_map', $multi_data);
$sizes = array();
foreach ($val_for_sizes as $vals) {
  $sizes[] = strlen(max($vals));
}


$rows = explode("|", $data);
$headers = "a,b,c,d";
array_unshift($rows, $headers);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $parts = explode(",", $row);
  $col = 0;
  foreach ($parts as $part) {
    echo str_pad($part, $sizes[$col++] + 1) . "|";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a       |b   |c   |d    |
100     |200 |30  |400  |
500     |600 |70  |8000 |
900     |100 |200 |300  |
4004532 |500 |60  |700  |
800     |900 |100 |200  |
300     |400 |500 |600  |
700     |800 |900 |100  |
```

Comment: thanks for the detail explaining so i accept this answer

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way

```
<?php
$data="100,200,300,400|500,600,700,800|900,100,200,300|400,500,600,700|800,900,100,200|300,400,500,600|700,800,900,100";
$data = explode('|',$data);
foreach($data as $d){
   $newdata_arr = explode(',',$d);
      foreach($newdata_arr as $newdata)
      echo $newdata."|";

   echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

### [demo](http://codepad.org/Fp70rTSU)

Comment: Thanks its work, it really easy but i am very n00b so i didnt know how to do this, and now i understand thank you

Comment: and sory if i accept sberry answer because he explain a lot....but thanks once again

Comment: @dpz its okay, even i would have preffered his answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = explode('|',$data);
$arr = array();
foreach($data as &$d)
    $arr[] = explode(',',$d);


<pre>
<?php print_r ($arr); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data="100,200,300,400|500,600,700,800|900,100,200,300|400,500,600,700|800,900,100,200|300,400,500,600|700,800,900,100";
$dt = $data = explode('|',$data);
echo 'a | b | c | d';
echo '<br/>';
foreach($dt as $key => $val){
  echo str_replace(',', ' | ',$val);
  echo '<br/>';
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<pre>
<?php print_r ($array); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Read the question to say the least.